# Remind Me in Mail.app has "1" indicator, even though no messages

Tags: icloud, mail.app, mobile-mail

I’m stuck with a notification of “1” message in my “Remind Me” mailbox, even though there *aren’t* any messages in there.

Any one know how to fix this? I’ve tried syncing (Mailbox > Synchronize “iCloud”) but it still shows “1” on both my MacBook and the same account in Mail.app on my iPhone.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What if you select the mailbox and then "Rebuild" from the Mailbox menu, that often fixes these "ghost message" indicators for me.